# Kotlin Native Cocoapods plugin - how to specify Podspec source?

Tags: gradle, cocoapods, kotlin-native

Now when generating podspec with Gradle I get

```
spec.source = { :git => "Not Published", :tag => "Cocoapods/#{spec.name}/#{spec.version}" }
```

How can I change `:git` and `:tag` here in Gradle in `cocoapods`?

```
cocoapods {
        // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
        def projectName = project.getRootProject().getName()
        summary = projectName
        ios.deploymentTarget = "9.0"
        // set git source here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default options for this.

If you want to change those fields content, you can follow the approach described https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42105.

For example, adding this code to your `build.gradle.kts` might do the trick:

```
val podspec = tasks["podspec"] as PodspecTask
podspec.doLast {
    val podspec = file("${project.name.replace("-", "_")}.podspec")
    val newPodspecContent = podspec.readLines().map {
        if (it.contains("spec.source")) "    spec.source = <some custom value>" else it
    }
    podspec.writeText(newPodspecContent.joinToString(separator = "\n"))
}
```

It interprets the podspec file as a text file and allows you to change it as you like to.